# Variable data corruption with C GCC on Fedora 17 64 bit

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, memory-alignment, memory-corruption

I am creating a temporary buffer and copying a string to the buffer using sprintf. I then call the function analyzeRecordForPGDBOperation passing the buffer as parameter. I Parse the string with strtok using | as delimiter. I see a strange problem the value of codesite is corrupted later on even though its printed correctly in switch case 2. The value of codesite is incorrect when i print in case 3 and case 4.

I tried to see the reson for it in gdb using a watch on the codesite variable, I get the following output but I am not sure why I get this issue.

> [root@pe1800xs64 trunk]# uname -r
>   3.9.10-100.fc17.x86_64

"Output from GDB:"

> Old value = "71663138", '\000' 
>   New value = "\000\061\066\066\063\061\063\070", '\000'
>
> 0x00000038f30939ee in __strcpy_sse2_unaligned () from /lib64/libc.so.6

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char tmp[256];
    sprintf(tmp, "%s", "99|71663138|316DEA40C62D6BA40B3C0AA2FE06C457|1442319758");
    analyzeRecordForPGDBOperation(tmp);
    return 0;
}

void analyzeRecordForPGDBOperation(char *data)
{
    char tempBuff[256] = {'\0',};
    char park[16] = {'\0',};
    char codesite[16] = {'\0',};
    char key[24] = {'\0',};
    char timestamp[16] = {'\0',};
    int caseVal = 0;
    sprintf(tempBuff, "%s", data);
    char *p = strtok(tempBuff,"|");

    for (; p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, "|"))
    {
        caseVal++;
        switch(caseVal)
        {
            case 1:
                sprintf(park, "%s", p);
                break;
            case 2:
                sprintf(codesite, "%s", p);
                //Value of codesite is printed correctly here
                printf("\nCodesite: %s\n", codesite);
                break;
            case 3:
                sprintf(key, "%s", p);
                //Value of codesite is corrupted
                printf("\nCodesite Case 3: %s\n", codesite);
                break;
            case 4:
                sprintf(timestamp, "%s", p);
                //Value of codesite is corrupted
                printf("\nCodesite case 4: %s\n", codesite);
                break;
            default:
                break;
       }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> [root@pe1800xs64 trunk]# ./a.out
>
> analyzeRecordForPGDBOperation
>
> Codesite: 71663138
>
> Codesite Case 3:
>
> Codesite case 4:

Comment: You are reading a 32-letter key into a 24-byte buffer. Ouch.

Comment: try increasing length of destination buffers

Comment: Never use `sprintf` but always use [snprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) e.g. `snprintf(timestamp, sizeof(timestamp), "%s", p);`; consider also [asprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html)

Comment: try not to run programs as root user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this `"316DEA40C62D6BA40B3C0AA2FE06C457"` is the value which you need to copy on your `case 3`, then the destination buffer `key` is not large enough.

This triggers undefined behavior and this is why you see strange result in `codesite` afterwards even though you didn't directly modify that.

Answer (score 0):

Size of buffer which I allocated was less. Buffer size is 24 while I am trying to copy 33 characters to it. Hence, the memory is corrupted.
With the new size the problem is solved.

char codesite[16] = {'\0',};
char key[35] = {'\0',};

Thanks for the help